# Beamer headline miniframes - two different colors

Tags: beamer, color, mini-frames

I am working with the Dresden style of `beamer`.  When I use smoothbars I get the color combination that I would like to have.  However, when I change to miniframes I cannot get the correct color combination.

Working code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx, natbib, lmodern, tikz}

\xdefinecolor{pgold}{rgb}{0.8,0.6,0.2}

\usetheme{Dresden}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 

\usecolortheme[named=pgold]{structure}
\beamertemplateballitem

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}


\title[xx]{lalala}
\author{me} 


\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}
{
\logo{\pgfuseimage{left-logo}}
\vfill%
\rlap{\hskip0.2cm\insertlogo}%
\vskip5pt%
}


% These next six lines declare a new beamerboxes environment
\setbeamercolor{uppercol}{fg=black,bg=purduegold}
\setbeamercolor{lowercol}{fg=black,bg=purduegold!20}
\newenvironment{colorblock}
{
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol,shadow=true]}
{\end{beamerboxesrounded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{1}
\begin{frame} \centering \huge
PAPER 1
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: How it looks with smoothbars]

However, when I change `\useoutertheme{smoothbars}` to `\useoutertheme{miniframes}`

The color of the presentation changes to to look like picture number two:

[image]

No matter what I change or add I cannot seem to fix it.  I really would like to use miniframes because I will have many sections and would like them to wrap around.

Comment: Although you're a member from 4 months, this is your first question, so [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we look inside `beamerouterthemesmoothbars.sty` and `beamerouterthememiniframes.sty`, we can see that the former uses `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette quaternary}` while the last uses `\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette tertiary}`.

`section in head/foot` beamercolor is the one used to include navigation in headline, so a possible solution could be to charge `miniframes` outer theme and, after that, change `section in head/foot` to the one used by `smoothbars`.

I'm not sure if this change will affect any other element.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx, natbib, lmodern, tikz}

\xdefinecolor{pgold}{rgb}{0.8,0.6,0.2}

\usetheme{Dresden}
%\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\useoutertheme{miniframes}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{parent=palette quaternary}

\usefonttheme{serif}
\usepackage{palatino}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
\setbeamercolor*{alerted text}{fg=red} 

\usecolortheme[named=pgold]{structure}
\beamertemplateballitem

\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{%
    \usebeamerfont{footline}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}%
    \hspace{1em}%
    \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}


\title[xx]{lalala}
\author{me} 


%\setbeamertemplate{sidebar left}
%{
%\logo{\pgfuseimage{left-logo}}
%\vfill%
%\rlap{\hskip0.2cm\insertlogo}%
%\vskip5pt%
%}


% These next six lines declare a new beamerboxes environment
\setbeamercolor{uppercol}{fg=black,bg=pgold}
\setbeamercolor{lowercol}{fg=black,bg=pgold!20}
\newenvironment{colorblock}
{
\begin{beamerboxesrounded}[upper=uppercol,lower=lowercol,shadow=true]}
{\end{beamerboxesrounded}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{1}
\begin{frame} \centering \huge
PAPER 1

\begin{colorblock}{Title}
This is a colorblock
\end{colorblock}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]